# Iterate through Files and pick the closest to my parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory, iteration

I'd like to iterate through a folder which can contain files with the following names:

1.xml
2.xml
3.xml
4.xml
etc..

Now I'd like to pick the file that is closest to the number I assign to the searchmethod but not higher than it.

e.g. in the Folder are 1, 3, 5 and 8.xml, my Parameter is 6, I see 6 isn't there, 8 is too high, pick 5 then!

I've already come across the `Directory.GetFiles`-Method, but since it returns the whole path this will be a rather nasty string-cutting and -comparing, is there a more elegant solution to my problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles`, in conjunction with [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

So, something like:

```
foreach (file in Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp")) 
{
    int myInt = Int32.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
}
```

One LINQ-y solution to your entire problem could be:

```
int maxFileId = 2;
int myFileNumber = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TEMP1\test\EnvVarTest\Testfiles")
    .Select(file => Int32.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)))
    .Where(i => i <= maxFileId)
    .Max();
```

Comment: Thanks, yours appears to be quickest Solution!

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty, with no check to ensure that filenames can actually be parsed to numbers (i.e. if non-numerically named XML files exist, this will fail). Left as an exercise to reader to harden this approach.

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\somePath" , "*.xml")
.Select(f => new{fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f) , path = f})
.Select(x => new{fileNum = int.Parse(x.fn) , x.path})
.OrderBy(x => x.fileNum)
.TakeWhile(x => x.fileNum <= MYPARAM)
.Select(x => x.path)
.LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: Did you perchance mean `path = x.fn` on line 3?

Comment: No, but there was a mistake. Corrected.

Comment: I like this solution as it returns the full path, rather than just the file-number. Probably more useful in most situations :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm clearly a slower typer than everyone else :) but i thought I would post it since I had written it.

```
class Program
{
    public class NumberedXmlFile
    {
        public NumberedXmlFile(string fullPath)
        {
            FullPath = fullPath;
        }
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
        public int FileNumber
        {
            get
            {
                string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullPath);

                return Convert.ToInt32(file);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int targetFileNameNumber = 4;
        const string directoryPathContainingFiles = @"C:\temp";

        IEnumerable<NumberedXmlFile> numberedXmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPathContainingFiles).Select(f => new NumberedXmlFile(f));

        NumberedXmlFile theFileIamLookingFor = numberedXmlFiles.OrderBy(f => Math.Abs(f.FileNumber - targetFileNameNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, also a nice approach!